# Wireless strength of a wifi modem

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

What specification of a Wifi Modem + Router(for a DSL connection) tells us about the strength of the wireless signals? i.e. one particular router may be give out signals strong enough to reach 1 room away another may give out signals which can reach in the floor below or above. So which parameter of the spec tells us about this capability of the wifi modem+router. And how to interpret this parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wireless Router Signal Strength Stats](http://superuser.com/questions/298290/wireless-router-signal-strength-stats)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say its the gain. A gain of an antenna is measured in **[dBi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBi#Antenna_measurements)**. The longer antenna with good gain (dBi) give a good wider coverage.

In common, a gain of antenna will be 2dBi (it may vary depending on some routers). 2dBi is pretty much enough to cover 70 - 100 meters. Usually for the signal strenght of a WiFi, its gain is more important (that is the antenna).

Comment: Can you clarify will 2dBi only work if your between 70-100 meters away from the source? if that's the max what would the min be?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly that's a fair question, and Azker has a very technical answer, but in reality, there is no way to tell how 1 router is going to react in it's environment. And the specifications are normally tested in an open area. But in a home settings, there are so many factors involved in how you're going to get a signal. ie. 2 Floors, the material your walls are made from, the way your house is shaped, or where you place your router in the first place could effect the signal.

Your question says wifi modem + router, I'm assuming you have a all in 1 modem/router from like AT&T or Verizon. If you gave us the model number, we might be able to give you some specs on that router but, normally those routers have very little details, and they are usually not very high end.

Now if we were talking in terms of only a router alone, the industry now focuses on something called the N network. It used to be the G network, now its N.

[image][image]

And N has many ranges, router manufactures use this range to determine the price they are going to charge you. I believe there are like 3 types: N150 N300 and N450+. Anyway, you'll never have a company say our router will give you THIS much range because of the factors i've discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter shows the strength of the signal is Transmit Power (Tx). It is common used in wireless router, but for wireless ADSL modem people focus more on the DSL part, sometimes this parameter is omitted in the datasheet. Anyhow you can check the vendor for the Tx strength value.
The unit of the Tx strength is dBm or mw. Some vendor may include the Tx of the PA only, and some may plus the gain of antenna. It is normally 15-20dBm for our wireless ADSL modem routers(http://www.visonicom.com/wireless-adsl-routers/), depending on the requirement of buyer.